# Warning: Internal React error: Expected static flag was missing. Please notify the React team

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Does anybody knows what could be wrong with this component?

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import React from 'react';

const ModalShop = ({ isVisible, onClose }) => {

    if (!isVisible) return null;

    const handleClose = (e) => {
        if (e.target.id === 'wrapper') { onClose(); }
    }

    const inputRef = useRef(null);
    const spanRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const input = inputRef.current;
        const span = spanRef.current;

        const handleInput = () => {
            if (input.value.trim() !== '') {
                span.classList.add('text-green-800', 'bg-slate-300', 'transform', '-translate-y-4', '-translate-x-0', 'text-sm', 'mx-4', 'px-1');
            } else {
                span.classList.remove('text-green-800', 'bg-slate-300', 'transform', '-translate-y-4', '-translate-x-0', 'text-sm', 'mx-4', 'px-1');
            }
        };

        input.addEventListener('input', handleInput);

        return () => {
            input.removeEventListener('input', handleInput);
        };

    }, []);
    

    return (
        <div className='fixed inset-0 right-30 bg-black
            bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm flex
            justify-center items-center z-30'
            onClick={handleClose}
            id='wrapper'
        >
            <div className='w-[300px] px-5 sm:w-[600px] sm:px-0 flex flex-col z-40'>
                <button className='text-white text-xl
                    place-self-end'
                    onClick={() => onClose()}
                >
                    x
                </button>
                <div className='bg-slate-300 p-2 rounded h-[300px] w-[auto] flex items-center'>
                    <label className='relative'>
                        <input type='text' className='h-[40px] w-[250px]
                            text-lg bg-slate-300 border-2 rounded-r-3xl
                            border-gray-600 outline-none
                            focus:border-green-800 focus:text-black
                            transition duration-200 px-2'
                            id="nombreCompleto" ref={inputRef}
                        />
                        <span className='text-lg text-gray-600 input-text
                            absolute left-0 top-2 mx-2 px-2' id="nombreCompletoLabel"
                            ref={spanRef}
                        >
                            Put Your Name Here
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ModalShop;
```

When the component is executed this warning is thrown

> Warning: Internal React error: Expected static flag was missing.
> Please notify the React team.
> ModalShop@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/components/ModalShop.jsx:10:34
> section
> Price@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/sections/Price.jsx:31:86
> Suspense div
> InnerLayoutRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:241:18
> RedirectErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9
> RedirectBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:24
> NotFoundErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9
> NotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:62
> LoadingBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:315:76
> ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:130:67
> InnerScrollAndFocusHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:151:9
> ScrollAndFocusHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:226:37
> RenderFromTemplateContext@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44
> OuterLayoutRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:325:209
> body html
> RedirectErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:72:9
> RedirectBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:80:24
> NotFoundErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:54:9
> NotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:62:62
> DevRootNotFoundBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/dev-root-not-found-boundary.js:32:24
> ReactDevOverlay@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9
> HotReload@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:295:37
> Router@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:159:100
> ErrorBoundaryHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:100:9
> ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:130:67
> AppRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:436:47
> ServerRoot@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:128:24
> RSCComponent
> Root@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:144:24

Comment: Likely due to your `if (!isVisible) return null;` occuring before the `useEffect`/`useRef` hook calls (a bit tired at the moment to verify the specific hook that causes it). See [this github issue thread](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24391#issuecomment-1107796997), in particular the comment I hardlinked in there.

Answer (score 6):

You are using hooks conditionally, which is against the rules of hooks. You need to move this line after all your hooks:

```
  if (!isVisible) return null;
```